# Split data into multiple sheets based on column

Tags: excel, vba

**#Modifying** Question for better understanding and how do i want the result is.

> Wizhi answer almost matched for my question !! But need some more
> changes in his answer because which code is not working for me !! And
> no need to work based on **GCN Date** as he answered. The split work
> done based on **Destination Pincode** .

Please help someone help me to Macro Code for Split data into multiple sheet within an excel workbook based on a table format. Below is the explanation of how i have done as per my knowledge and what is my expectation is !!

**"Here is the workbooks what i have Done"**

Please download the [Macro_Folder](https://www.dropbox.com/t/anX1TF2qb04cjO5r) and Unzip it in you "C" Drive.
Open Macro Workbook and Press Button to run macro.

If it asked for updating formulas as shown in below picture please select "Don't Update" to continue macro.

[image]

**My Macro workbook view :**

I Have done button option to Run the split macro in separate excel workbook.

[image]

**Where the files Located**

When self open and run Macro from Macro Workbook it automatically opens my **XD MIS Report** and start formatting and split the date into multiple sheets.

[image]

View of XD MIS is **"Master Data"** which is having overall raw data.

[image]

Here is the view after self Run Macro fro split Master data.

[image]

**Code that i Used For Split Data into Multiple Sheet:**

```
Sub Spli_Data()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myfilename As String
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
    
myfilename = "C:\Macro\XD MIS Report.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myfilename)

    Cells.Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Columns("B:F").Select
    Range("B2").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:E").Select
    Range("D2").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Range("H2").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("K:L").Select
    Range("K2").Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Range("D2").Activate
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Range("K2").Activate
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("K1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Remarks"
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Packing Type"
    Range("H1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-1]C[6]:RC[6],RC[6])"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R1C7:RC[6],RC[6])"
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range("A2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1:L3100").Select
    Range("A2").Activate
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With
    With Selection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri Light"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With
    Range("A2").Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    vcol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", title:="Filter column", Default:="3", Type:=1)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Result Of Split Data What i have right now:**

**Destination 1**

[image]

**Destination 2**

[image]

**Now Let's  Clear About My Requirement:**

1. I have done macro for format and Split Data into multiple Sheet,But this the not exact format result which i'm looking for.
2. The split should be done in same method but for result format should be like below formats based on macro code.
3. The split data should be in **Multiple sheets of within an Excel Workbook** . Not split to multiple workbooks !!

**Write a macro for split Data in this format** for all **Destination Pincode:**

---

> This how i'm expecting final result through macro code

---

Expected Format of **#Destination 1 Sample** After Split done

[image]

**#Destination 1 Sample**

[image]

> This is an examples of what i'm looking for.  The same have to done
> for all destination which is in **Master Data**

**Hope !! now my question is clear for better understanding and easy to answer.**

Comment: Have you looked into using AdvancedFilter? [Advanced Filter Tutorial](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/2/16/advanced-filters-with-vba-to-automate-filtering-on-and-out-specific-values)

Comment: What is the name of the destination sheet? Is it the same as the value from destination pincode?

Comment: You are better off accessing the cell values directly rather than copy pasting. The requirement #3 is not very clear. Could you illustrate with an example please.

Comment: This question is broad and somewhat unclear. Cleaning that up will help you get more useful answers but _"Help me to get **exact** code"_ might still be too high of hopes. Most answers on this site aren't 100% plug and play. Is it _Create a new workbook with one worksheet per pincode (same as main table but less data rows (filtered for pincode) and several meta header rows)._ ?? I'm still very unclear on requirement #3 but #s 1, 2, and 4 all seem to say the same thing.

Comment: @Joey No I haven't used advance filter !!! We don't have these option in our office system.

Comment: @SiddharthRout The destination sheet name should be named as Splitting Destination Pincode Name !!

Comment: @MarkBalhoff I have written clearly that what i need exactly.  I have an Master Data that data have to split into multiple sheet based on my second Picture table format !! The #3 statement is may be the data values fills the cells lesser or more in between headers and bottom total. So that have to be auto adjusted through Code when splitting the master Data.

Comment: Hi All !! I Have Changed My Entire Question for better understanding. Hope now it's easy to answer.

Comment: What happens if a client choose 3, as this is your default option in the InputBox? What's the meaning with InputBox if you can't split data by other columns than Destination Pincode? Shouldn't that part be removed? What should happen if someone choose 2?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the code to split data from **Master Data** -> **XD_Booking_Data** -> Split into worksheets based on Destination Pincode?

Comment: Yes @Wizhi . Only split have to done based on Destination Pincode, and the final should be in format which i shown in last picture. Can u please help me out !

Comment: @Wizhi That final format should be applied for all Split data sheets. And the data split done within an excel workbook by Destination Pincode and "Name" of sheet also same.

Comment: Opps ! U Confused the name Master data!! Master data means = XD MIS Report.

Comment: @Wizhi i have clearly modified complete question .  U can see what  result i got after i use my macro code through macro work book for format and Splitting data from XD MIS Report. But my result is not met my exception format. #The final format. You already done that format method in your code . but your code not working in my excel. please modify my query to add Final format. I Need the final result should be like above Pictures which is in last of my question.

Comment: @Wizhi Hope u understood !! I'm Bad in communication :-( . I hope you can do my need . Please help me out for this !!

Comment: I am very happy question is finally resolved.. ps: write "I" instead of "i"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updated code:

@Mark Balhoff, Thanks for your valuable input, I always like to learn and get feedback to improve myself :). I have used your input in the code and also extended it a bit.

---

This code is using dictionary so you need to activate "`Microsoft Scripting Runtime`"

- "Tools" -> "References" -> "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to make dictionary work

[image]

**User process to split Master Data:**

I assume that the user will split this data in the picture:
Pressing the button, it will choose column 7.
*(My opinion is that this part with InputBox etc... is unnecessary as you always want to filter by column 7 regardless, so I feel it confused the end user)*

**Is quite unclear from what "raw data" you start with as new pictures/data have appeared in the updated question. I have assumed that the data that we should split looks like this, as it was stated first**

[image]

- Output of the first unique Destination Pincode:

[image]

- Output of the second unique Destination Pincode:

[image]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Split()

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lc As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws_new As Worksheet
    
    Dim DestPincode As Range
    Dim DestPincodeCol As Long
    
    Dim vcol As Long
    Dim vcol_value As String
    Dim vcol_name As String
    Dim vcol_prompt As String
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Dim DestPincode_ws_new As Range
    Dim DestPincodeCol_ws_new As Long
    Dim DestPincodeRow_ws_new As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    '##### SETTINGS #####
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master_Data") 'Set master data sheet
    Set DestPincode = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Find(What:="Destination Pincode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'Set name to search after, i.e. Destination
    '####################
    
    
    lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Find last column in Master Data
    DestPincodeCol = DestPincode.Column 'Get column number for Destination Pincode
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, DestPincodeCol).End(xlUp).Row 'Get last row
    
    
    'This macro splits data into multiple worksheets based on the variables on a column found in Excel.
    'An InputBox asks you which columns you'd like to filter by, and it just creates these worksheets.
    
    '##### Filter based on InputBox #####
    vcol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", title:="Filter column", Default:="7", Type:=1)
    If vcol <> 7 Then Exit Sub
    
    '##### Get all the uniqe "Destination Pincodes" #####
    ' You need to activate "Tools" -> "References" -> "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to make dictionary work
    Dim DestPincodeData()
    Dim UniqueDestPincodeData As Object
    Dim DestPinRow As Long
    
    Set UniqueDestPincodeData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    DestPincodeData = Application.Transpose(ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, DestPincodeCol), ws.Cells(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, DestPincodeCol).End(xlUp).Row, DestPincodeCol))) 'Get all the Destination Pincode values
    
    For DestPinRow = 2 To UBound(DestPincodeData, 1) 'Start from row 2 (to skip header) and add unique values to the dictionary
        UniqueDestPincodeData(DestPincodeData(DestPinRow)) = 1 'Add value to dictionary
    Next
    
    
    '##### Loop through all the unqie Destination Pincodes and add to seperate workbooks #####
    Dim new_wb As Workbook
    Set new_wb = Application.Workbooks.Add 'Add new workbook
    'Set new_wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Dim DestPincodeName As Variant
    Dim MyRangeFilter As Range
    
    Set MyRangeFilter = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, lc)) 'Filter range 'Set filter range
    
    For Each DestPincodeName In UniqueDestPincodeData.Keys 'Filter through all the unique names in dictionary "UniqueDestPincodeData"
        'Debug.Print "Destination Pincode: " & DestPincodeName 'Print current unique Destination Pincode name
        
        'Filter the data based on "Destination Pincode" and Column from InputBox
        
        With MyRangeFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=DestPincodeCol, Criteria1:=DestPincodeName, Operator:=xlFilterValues 'Filter on Destination Pincode
        End With
        
        '##### Create new workbook for the filtered data #####
        'To add to new worksheet:
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = DestPincodeName
        Set ws_new = new_wb.Worksheets(DestPincodeName)
        


        '##### Create template in the new workbook #####
        'Building template output, row by row
        
        ws_new.Range("A1:A7").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose( _
                        Array("*******", "TRIP NO", "TRIP DATE/TIME", "TRUCKTYPE (OWN/ATT/ADHOC)", "SEAL #", "SUPERVISOR NAME", "REMARK"))
        ws_new.Range("H2:H6").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose( _
                        Array("VEHICLE NO", "VEHICLE CAPACITY", "DRIVER NAME", "DRIVER NO", "VENDOR NAME"))
        
        Dim Top_Area_Cell_Format As Range
        
        
        Set Top_Area_Cell_Format = ws_new.Range("A1:L1,A7:L7,A2:D2,E2:G2,H2:I2,J2:L2," _
                        & "A3:D3,E3:G3,H3:I3,J3:L3,A4:D4,E4:G4,H4:I4," _
                        & "J4:L4,A5:D5,E5:G5,H5:I5,J5:L5,A6:D6,E6:G6,H6:I6,J6:L6")
                        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Top_Area_Cell_Format.Merge 'Merge cells
            Top_Area_Cell_Format.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft 'Make title in center
            Top_Area_Cell_Format.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous 'Add border lines
            Top_Area_Cell_Format.Font.Bold = True 'Add Bold text
            ws_new.Range("A1:L1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 'Make title in center
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
        '##### Paste filtered data from Master_Data sheet #####
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, lc)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 'Make text in center
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, lc)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy 'Copy entire row from filtered data
        ws_new.Cells(8, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'Paste all values including formats
        
        Set DestPincode_ws_new = ws_new.Range(ws_new.Cells(8, 1), ws_new.Cells(1, ws_new.Cells(8, ws_new.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Find(What:="Destination Pincode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'Set name to search after, i.e. Destination
        DestPincodeCol_ws_new = DestPincode_ws_new.Column
        DestPincodeRow_ws_new = ws_new.Cells(ws_new.Rows.Count, DestPincodeCol_ws_new).End(xlUp).Row
          
          
        'Add total
        ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "A").Value = "TOTAL"
        ws_new.Range(ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "A"), ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "G")).Merge 'Merge cells
        ws_new.Range(ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "A"), ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "G")).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 'Make text in center
        ws_new.Range(ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "A"), ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "G")).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous 'Add border lines
        ws_new.Range(ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "A"), ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "G")).Font.Bold = True 'Add Bold text
        
        'Add total values
        ws_new.Range(ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "I"), ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "I")).Formula = "=SUM(I9:I" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new & ")" 'Add sum for "No. of cartons"
        ws_new.Range(ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "J"), ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "J")).Formula = "=SUM(J9:J" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new & ")" 'Add sum for "Actual weights"
        ws_new.Range(ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "H"), ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "L")).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous 'Add border lines
        ws_new.Range(ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "H"), ws_new.Cells(DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 1, "L")).Font.Bold = True 'Add Bold text
        
        '##### Add sign boxes #####
        Dim Bottom_Area_Cell_Text_Rng As String
        Dim Bottom_Area_Cell_Format As String
        Dim Bottom_Area_Cell_Format_rng As Range
            
        Bottom_Area_Cell_Text_Rng = "B" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 2 & ":H" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 2
        ws_new.Range(Bottom_Area_Cell_Text_Rng).Value = Array("Driver Signature", "", "Incharge Signature", "", "Security Signature", "", "REMARK")
        
        Bottom_Area_Cell_Format = "A" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 2 & ":A" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 4 & "," _
            & "B" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 2 & ":C" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 4 & "," _
            & "D" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 2 & ":E" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 4 & "," _
            & "F" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 2 & ":G" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 4 & "," _
            & "H" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 2 & ":L" & DestPincodeRow_ws_new + 4
        
        Set Bottom_Area_Cell_Format_rng = ws_new.Range(Bottom_Area_Cell_Format)
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Bottom_Area_Cell_Format_rng.Merge 'Merge cells
            Bottom_Area_Cell_Format_rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft 'Make title in center
            Bottom_Area_Cell_Format_rng.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous 'Add border lines
            Bottom_Area_Cell_Format_rng.VerticalAlignment = xlTop 'Alignment of text
            Bottom_Area_Cell_Format_rng.Font.Bold = True 'Add Bold text
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
        
        'Adjust Column width
        ws_new.Columns("A:L").Select
        Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
        Set ws_new = Nothing 'Reset worksheet value
                
    Next
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        new_wb.Worksheets(1).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Sheet1.ShowAllData 'remove filter
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Link to workbook:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/86wlv99y6wylpn8/split%20data.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Admirable level of effort on screenshots, explanation, and code especially for an unclear and broad question. I hope the OP appreciates your effort and tries to understand it. One comment, I have only skimmed your code because it's verbose. I would expect it to overwhelm a new coder and make a veteran coder not read it. A little cleanup would make it more readable, more maintainable, quicker to write, and less error-prone. For example, [here is a quick mockup](https://pastebin.com/586RbyfN) of 9 lines of code equivalent to 38 lines in your code. This does the top 7 rows of output worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time taken for to answer my question !! Sorry to say that !! this is not result i'm looking for !! Now i have modified my question for better understanding what i need the exact final result. Please go through once again do me favor please!!

Comment: @MarkBalhoff now i have done modification f my entire question. Hope it's understandable now !!

Comment: @Wizhi You almost done as i have expected !! but no need to work on GCN Date . Only need to split done based destination Pincode !!   as i told now i modified y question pls go though it and do me favor pls.

Comment: This answer shows, indeed, pretty good effort and it's really close to what ypu are looking for. Are you telling that you are not doing nothing at all except if somebody shows **Exactly 100% accuracy** code? because this code is almost what you need, you just need some fixes.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff, thanks for pointing out. It makes me improve and honestly I think my patiance run out as the question is indeed very vague. You have right that the way you wright is more clean and takes a lot of space (I'm not sure it easier to understand for a new person, i.e. arrays etc..). But I will think about it and see if I update my code. Thanks!

Comment: at:FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, I agree with you, the OP should be ready to do some work, smaller adjustments... @regiz. I doesn't seems like you have tried or test or play around with this code.... You write that you want it in seperate worksheet, you have the code for that in this one. I don't think you'll get a 100% code, it's you almost always need to adjust/amend code to your own project.... I'll see what I can do but I don't think you can expect a code that will do 100% as I'm quite sure that you will need to modify a bit for your needs.

Comment: @Wizhi please read my new modified question once again !! Hope it's understandable now . Please Look at the final Pic that's what i want as result after split data into multiple sheet within an Excel workbook.

Comment: Updated code as per request. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Wizhi the code looks fine !! But it's not working for me Giving Error as "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" and The Debug Stops is "Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master_Data") 'Set master data sheet" This comment :-(

Comment: @Wizhi But which is working in your workbook  which u gave as link. but not working when i copy paste and work. I have done all that you said in your first point.

Comment: @Wizhi I understood that still u need clarification of my way of working . Let me clear you. 1. I have Separate Work Books for Macro and Raw Data (XD MIS Report) U can refer my second image. 2.In Macro Workbook I have done button option to Run Macro. 3. The Macro Automatically Opens "XD MIS Report" Workbook and start formatting based    on My Code . 4. Once Format Completed I get Only Required Columns . 5. Then the same macro split Data into multiple sheets based on "Destination Pincode"  which is in 7th Column. This is what i have done.  But the final result is not in my expected format.

Comment: @Wizhi Please refer the links of my work books . 1. Unzip that Folder in your local "C:" Drive and Run Macro though "Macro Work Book" Then u will understand what i have done. Once u got it please add your codes into that for Split data based on my required format.

Comment: @Wizhi When u trying to run my macro which will ask enable to update formulas. Just Select  "Dont' Update" Then the macro will continue work.

Comment: @Wizhi sorry for disturbing you again and again!! Now u can understand what i have done and what is my exception. Please change your codes based on my method. And it have to work in my end.

Comment: @Wizhi you are excellent!! Fabulous!! You done great help to me !! Finlay It's working fine !! . Please update the code in your answer :-)\

Comment: Thanks Ton @Wizhi You Done Great Job !! Never forgot your help !!! It's really working awesome. Love you buddy :-)

Comment: You have used `Dim UniqueDestPincodeData As Object` and `Set UniqueDestPincodeData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`, which is used in case of `Late Binding` which is preferred when sending the final product to a user. This does not require a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. The early binding would have been, which I prefer: `Dim UniqueDestPincodeData As Scripting.Dictionary` and `Set UniqueDestPincodeData = New Scripting.Dictionary`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure If I've understand properly, but it looks like you want to split your data depending on the value of `PINCODE` column.

Besides, your question is too broad right now, you should focus more.

So, as example, I understand you would select all rows containing `PINCODE=PUZHAL`, and copy all of them into a different workbook.

And you want this for each unique `PINCODE`.

I made a fake dataset coloring rows, and I split the data into new workbooks. You'll need to adapt this to paste the data into existing workbooks (or new worksheets of same workbook, whatever)

My data is like this:

[image]

My code:

```
Sub TEST()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim MyDict As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim MyKey As Variant
Dim LR As Long

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim MyRows As Variant



LR = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


For i = 2 To LR Step 1
    If MyDict.Exists(Range("G" & i).Value) = False Then
        'we create the PINCODE in Dictionary and assign row number
        MyDict.Add Range("G" & i).Value, i
    Else
        'PINCODE already in Dictionary, we add the new row number
        MyDict(Range("G" & i).Value) = MyDict(Range("G" & i).Value) & "|" & i
    End If
Next i

'now Dictionary holds all pincodes and all row numbers for each pincode.
'we create a workbook for each PINCODE, but you can adapt this to open a exact workbook depending on PINCODE
'I'm copying the rows starting at row 1, but you can adapt this to your model for sure


For Each MyKey In MyDict.Keys

    Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Add
    LR = 1 'change this to starting row
    MyRows = Split(MyDict(MyKey), "|") 'we create array of rows numbers
    
    
    For i = LBound(MyRows) To UBound(MyRows) Step 1
        'we copy range A:L from that row into destiny workbook
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & MyRows(i) & ":L" & MyRows(i)).Copy WB.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LR & ":L" & LR)
        LR = LR + 1 'we increase LR so next data will be pasted into next row
    Next i
    
    Erase MyRows
    Set WB = Nothing
    DoEvents
Next MyKey

MyDict.RemoveAll
Set MyDict = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And this is how i get all my data splitted into different files depending on `PINCODE`.

[image]

Comment: Sorry !! This is not result i'm looking for !! Anyway thanks for your answer and time !! I have done modification in my question for better understanding. Please go through it and do me favor if you can :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest You create a Pivot Table.
By that Pivot table you create a code to extract data on a pivotable  base on a list and transfer that to the formatted workbook you created and make a loop until the last Destination Pincode. I also use Excel VBA Form to Trigger this. I can make you one if you post your Excel here.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a macro that transfers the selected value from the dropdown list to the sheet with the same name as the value. I recommend that you review it.

[image]

Source : [Split data into multiple sheets](https://eksi30.com/excel-macro-to-parse-data-into-sheets/)